# Does the ejabberd nodes that are to be clustered should be under the same domain?

Tags: ejabberd

I am trying to setup a cluster of ejabberd on AWS EC2. And I have run into the above doubt that whether the nodes should be under one domain to be clustered.And can anyone explain how cluster setup works?

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of ejabberd clustering is to be able to use several servers for a single or small group of large domains, for fault-tolerance and scalability.

So, if you want to run two domains, you may not need clustering. You may simply want to run two different independant servers.

If your questions if if the cluster node need to run in a single Amazon region: The clustering in ejabberd Community Edition rely on low latency network. While it may work across region, it is recommended that you run an ejabberd cluster in a single Amazon region.

You can find more information on clustering in ejabberd documentation: [ejabberd clustering: How it works](http://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/guide/clustering/).

Comment: How does the ejabberd nodes perform discovery of other nodes in the cluster

Comment: They do not "discover" each other automatically. You have to add them explicitly to the ejabberd cluster schema.

Comment: I have two servers
`192.168.0.1`->"ejabberd@first"
`192.168.0.2`->"ejabberd@second"